# fetch multiple attributes in xpath3

Tags: xml, mule, xpath-3.0

I have to fetch all attributes by name 'product-id' when the currency of that pricebook is 'GBP'. This expression is working fine when xpath is used. But when I use xpath3, it returns only the first matching value instead of all the values. All I need is an equivalent expression of xpath in xpath3

*working xpath expression*:

**#[xpath:/pricebooks/pricebook[./header/currency ="GBP"]/price-tables/price-table/@product-id]**

xpath expression I tried:

**#[xpath3('/pricebooks/pricebook[./header/currency ="GBP"]/price-tables/price-table/@product-id',payload,'STRING')]**

**expected** : [product1,product2,product4]

**actual** : product1

INPUT XML:

```
<pricebooks>
 <pricebook>
    <header pricebook-id="GB">
        <currency>GBP</currency>
        <display-name>name1</display-name>
    </header>
    <price-tables>
        <price-table product-id="product1">
            <amount quantity="1">24.0</amount>
        </price-table>
    </price-tables>
 </pricebook>
 <pricebook>
    <header pricebook-id="NZ">
        <currency>GBP</currency>
        <display-name>name2</display-name>
    </header>
    <price-tables>
        <price-table product-id="product2">
            <amount quantity="1">38.00003</amount>
        </price-table>
    </price-tables>
 </pricebook>
 <pricebook>
    <header pricebook-id="US">
        <currency>USD</currency>
        <display-name>name3</display-name>
    </header>
    <price-tables>
        <price-table product-id="A215ZZ003">
            <amount quantity="1">28.0</amount>
        </price-table>
    </price-tables>
 </pricebook>
 <pricebook>
    <header pricebook-id="AU">
        <currency>GBP</currency>
        <display-name>name4</display-name>
    </header>
    <price-tables>
        <price-table product-id="product4">
            <amount quantity="1">30.0</amount>
        </price-table>
    </price-tables>
  </pricebook>
</pricebooks>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with mule, but your `xpath3()` parameter seems to have conflicting quotes, try to use double-quotes within your XPath : `'/pricebooks/pricebook[./header/currency ="GBP"]/price-tables/price-table/@product-id'`

Comment: I was using double quotes. Sorry for posting it wrong here. Updated it.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the third parameter in your attempted use of `xpath3()` is wrong. Try using **`NODESET`** instead of `STRING` since you mean to return multiple nodes.

Quoted from [the documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/xpath#return-type-string-optional) :

- **`BOOLEAN`**: Returns the effective boolean value of the expression as a `java.lang.String`. Equivalent to wrapping the expression in a call of the XPath `boolean()` function.
- **`STRING`**: Returns the result of the expression converted to a string, as a `java.lang.String`. Equivalent to wrapping the expression in a call to the XPath `string()` function.
- **`NUMBER`**: Returns the result of the expression converted to a double as a `java.lang.Double`. Equivalent to wrapping the expression in a call of the XPath `number()` function.
- **`NODE`**: Returns the result as a node object.
- **`NODESET`**: Returns a DOM `NodeList` object.

Comment: Changing the last parameter to 'NODESET' didnt work. I guess it is the return type after selection. Here problem is with selecting multiple values itself

Comment: The selection is fine, AFAICS. The XPath should returns all matching nodes by default, even in XPath 3. Here an XPath 3.0 demo : http://xpatheval.apphb.com/Dq0u8Rfx3 .

Comment: #[xpath3('//@product-id ')]   this expression also gives a single value instead of all matching values

Comment: I guess this must be a problem with mule as the expression is working fine in the evaluator u showed.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this helps,

/pricebooks/pricebook/price-tables/price-table[contains(@product-id,'product')]/@product-id

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).